# Python-MySQLdb, how do you access the exception error-code in `OperationalError`?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I need to catch a specific `OperationalError` exception. The exception text uses the error-code 2006. The library defines the error-codes at `MySQLdb.constants.CR.SERVER_GONE_ERROR = 2006`.

**How do you get the error-code from the exception?**

When I check the MySQLdb._mysql_exceptions, there is a definition of the OperationalError exception but it has no constructor or description of how to access the exception error code.

Comment: does the documentation or python code explain/show anywhere how to get the error-code? if yes, where?

Comment: every `Exception` object (which can be obtained with `try-except` block) has `args` field, have you tried to look at it?

Comment: i know that i could probably reverse engineer "something". but who knows if the "something" i come up with is good/correct. for instance, I could just do a `re.search(r'2006', str(exc))` but that doesn't seem very good IMO. I was hoping there was proper way to look at code/documentation (foolish i know right?).

Comment: you should look in source files for places where exceptions are raised if they go with error status code or they are inserted in error messages

Comment: in situations like this i usually use debugging and look what exception object consist of, if there any possibility to get status code separately, if no way -- then it is time for shitty coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the error number like the following:

```
try:
            # Adding field 'Bug.bize_size_tag_name'
            db.add_column('search_bug', 'bize_size_tag_name', orm['search.bug:bize_size_tag_name'])
except MySQLdb.OperationalError, errorCode:
            if errorCode[0] == 1060:
                pass
            else:
                raise
```

Reference: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/2584/MySQLdb.OperationalError