# How to access error code in MySQL python library exceptions

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, error-handling, mysql-python

I use the code from this question to catch operational errors: [Python-MySQLdb, how do you access the exception error-code in `OperationalError`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663130/python-mysqldb-how-do-you-access-the-exception-error-code-in-operationalerror)

```
try:
            # Adding field 'Bug.bize_size_tag_name'
            db.add_column('search_bug', 'bize_size_tag_name', orm['search.bug:bize_size_tag_name'])
except MySQLdb.OperationalError, errorCode:
            if errorCode[0] == 1060:
                pass
            else:
                raise
```

However I cannot access the error code. I get error:

```
  File "main.py", line 835, in db_execute
    if errorCode[0] == 1213:
TypeError: 'OperationalError' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Try `print(dir(errorCode))` and see if it lists any attributes

Comment: Did you tried to access the `errorCode.args`?

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for your code, solved

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @roganjosh comment to question I discovered the attributes of OperationalError:

```
['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', '__weakref__', 'args', 'with_traceback']
```

The error code was in attribute `args[0]`

Comment: Although, comments are liable to be deleted, so I think it would be worth formalizing the steps you used to solve this. If my comment is deleted, your answer will make little sense.